# Java: varargs declared constructor

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory, variadic-functions

I'm trying to use a factory design pattern to instantiate objects. Although, the constructor has a varargs parameter.

```
public class Foo implements Bar

public Foo(Object... args) {
}
```

In the factory I'm trying to get the constructor like this:

```
private Constructor<Bar> getConstructor(Class<Bar> clazz) {
    return clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(Object.class);
}
```

But it doesn't work. I've also tried:

```
private Constructor<Bar> getConstructor(Class<Bar> clazz) {
    return clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(Object[].class);
}
```

But I'll lose the 0 parameter functionality of varargs.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `But it doesn't work.`  Can you explain what is not working ?

Comment: It throws `NoSuchMethodException`

Comment: "But I'll lose the 0 parameter functionality of varargs." <-- uh, no you won't. It is legal to have an array with no elements at all...

Comment: It is, but I'll need to pass always an argument

Comment: Well, no. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varargs parameter is really an array parameter that have special handling by compiler and some other tools. So you can't use it as varargs parameters with reflection - you have to use it as array.

There is more flexible way to deal with methods - [`MethodHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) class from `java.lang.invoke` package. With method handle you can not only invoke this method but transform arguments to use different types than method signature have.

To use varargs constructor you can do this:

```
MethodHandle constructor = MethodHandles.publicLookup().findConstructor(Foo.class, Object[].class);
constructor.invoke(new Object(), 1, "");
```

Comment: @Lucas Unfortunately, no, this is a Java 7 feature. In Java 6 you have to create array explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'll lose the 0 parameter functionality of varargs.

Have you tried? You will not lose this "0 parameter functionality". It is legal to have an array with no elements at all.

You know the prototype for `main()`, right? `public static void main(String... args)`. And as I am sure you already know this can also be written as `public static void main(String[] args)`.

And you can very well invoke your main with:

```
 java [whatever JVM args here] path.to.my.MainClass
```

ie, no argument. There *will* be an array allocated, with no elements.

So, your second code will work even in that case.

Also, if you declare at least one constructor in a class, the default, no-arg constructor will not be generated. So, in the end, you are "safe".

Comment: Thanks for trying to to help. I can pass that block of code with that but I'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments` on this block `getConstructor(clazz).getNewInstance(args);` I'm passing 2 arguments...

Comment: You can't use reflection to invoke methods as taking varargs parameter.

Comment: This is normal; you need to build an array with these two arguments: `.newInstance(new Object[] { arg1, arg2 })`

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov wrong, you can; you just have to remind that varargs is just a syntactic sugar for an array

Comment: Well, I guess I wasn't clear enough. Of course you can pass an array - I mean that you can't pass many arguments to be collected in array as for varargs call. Also varargs not just syntax sugar - there is a way to use varargs at runtime - see my answer.